# code after socket statement does not execute

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

currently I'm working on a project which need socket programming, but unfortuanatly when i use to call the socket statement and read something from the input stream of the socket or write something to it the application crash and nothing will work, in fact the problem is that the code which handles the action of buttons and some other things will not work, the execution will stop at the line which calls the method that create the reads the input stream of socket. I solved this problem some times ago with the thread and by putting the statement which works with the socket inside the run method. the UI works correctly but i still do not have the good functionality. here is the two line of calling the method

```
Conection_Manager cm = new Conection_Manager(jTextField1.getText());
jTextArea1.setText(cm.getMessage());
```

in the first line I use to call the method in my connection manager class there the data on the socket will be read correctly and I can see that by printing those data, but when in the next line I want to set the text area with the string every thing crash. if it makes sense I use those two lines of statement inside a Jdialog
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is blocking waiting for something to be written to the socket. That's why it appears crashed, when in fact it is just waiting for data. have you checked that data is actually being written to the socket?

Also, Server Sockets block until a connection is received if you are doing everything in one thread (without an Executor, e.g)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that by *crashing* you mean it hangs. This is because you were trying to execute lengthy operations inside so called *event dispatching thread*, which handles all Swing events. Your solution with spawning a new thread for socket connectivity is correct, but instead of waiting for thread to finish (once again, blocking EDT), you need to update the GUI from the spawned thread.

But be careful, this is tricky, as Swing is in general not thread-safe, which means you cannot simply update controls from other threads. Try [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and make sure you read about EDT, for instance: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Threads/swing.